# Увеличивавет ли размер структуры определение вложенной структуры?

Tags: c#, .net, struct

Если структура содержит в себе определение другой структуры, не увеличивает ли это ее размер?

Простой пример:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct D2D1Matrix_3X2F
{
    public D2DMatrix_3X2FUnion U;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
    public struct D2DMatrix_3X2FUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] private MyStruct SomeField;

        struct MyStruct
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Определение — нет, но вот дополнительное поле `U` — да.

Comment: @VladD: Запишите как ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, определения типов внутри не увеличивают размер вашей структуры. Например, вот такой код

```
class Program
{
    unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sizeof(NoEmbeddedTypes));
        Console.WriteLine(sizeof(WithEmbeddedTypes));
    }
}

struct NoEmbeddedTypes
{
    int field;
}

struct WithEmbeddedTypes
{
    int field;
    struct EmbeddedType { int field; }
}
```

выдаст в обоих строках 4.

Вложенные типы являются лишь метаданными, и не присутствуют в объектах в явном виде. Однако, если вы кладёте в объект *поле*, тип которого определён внутри, то тогда размер вашей структуры зависит от размера поля, то есть, в конечном итоге, от внутреннего типа.

---

P. S.: Я не нашёл гарантии этому в спецификации языка, так что если вы пишете переносимую программу, имеет смысл стараться не сильно зависеть от обсуждаемого факта.

Comment: А еще там есть баги с загрузкой типов, если тип находится в библиотеке :)

Comment: @LLENN: Интересно! А где почитать об этом?